# suppressed if duplicates based on another item in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

in my crystal report i have data like this:

```
LOCNAME    DATE     Tbarcode  name
addrss     10/9/2103   12       jas
           10/9/2103   11     jas
           10/9/2103    4     ver

dubai      10/15/2013   6      jas
           10/9/2103     7      swev
            10/15/2013   8     jas
```

in this i grouped LOCNAME,DATE
i want to date supressed if duplicated on the same LOCNAME 
first i given

> suppress if duplicated

..but that is not working
 ..so i created formula like this

```
{LootTrans.LocName}=Previous({LootTrans.LocName}) and {LootTrans.Recieved_Date_Time}=Previous({LootTrans.Recieved_Date_Time})..but this is not working
```

Comment: Are you asking a question or telling an answer?

Comment: sir asking question ,,,this formula is not working

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have first group as LOCNAME and below that second group as DATE in crystal reports. Considering this assumption your report will bring data somthing like below,

```
LOCNAME    DATE     Tbarcode    name
addrss     10/9/2103   12       jas
addrss     10/9/2103   11       jas
addrss     10/9/2103    4       ver

dubai      10/15/2013   6       jas
dubai      10/9/2103    7      swev
dubai      10/15/2013   8       jas
```

Then you will check Suppress if duplicated checkbox for both LOCNAME and DATE column. This will bring your output as shown below,

```
LOCNAME      DATE     Tbarcode  name
addrss     10/9/2103   12       jas
                       11       jas
                        4       ver
```

Comment: sir i cheked if duplicated checkbox for both LOCNAME and DATE column,but still my date is replicationg ,,is any other way to supress my date if duplicate

Comment: Hi, this should have helped you. Can you please send me screenshot of the output after following above steps?

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on the field you want to suppress (LocName and Date), click on the Common tab and then check the Suppress if Duplicated box.

Answer (score 0):

the first thing
not create any group
step #2
right-click on the field you want to suppress (LocName and Date), click on the
Common tab and then check the Suppress if Duplicated box.
step #3 it most important step
in your query add
order by LocName , Date